# Laravel Error - Send notification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

is there any ways to handle error event (etc. send email, notification to webmaster) whenever a person encounter the error page (Whoops, looks like something wrong) in the system? Thanks

Comment: See `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` in your Laravel folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are trying to handle errors and exceptions caused to due some mistake in code you should refer this [page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors).
But if you are looking to make custom pages to handle specific error codes like 302,404,403 then you just have to make an html/php page displaying what you want just save it by the error code name for which you have made that page for.
For ex. 404.php, 403.php
Save this files under `views/errors/`

Answer (score 1):

There is a error log file

```
storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Open it with any Text editor and you can find all error logs.